# Make iPad-xib from iPhone-xib

Tags: iphone, ipad, xib, xcode4, universal

I am searching the web for a while now and didn´t find the answer...

is it possible in Xcode4 to convert an iPhone.xib to an iPad.xib when upgrading to a universal-app?!?
in Xcode 3 there was a possibility to create an ipad.xib from a selected iphone.xib. is this feature still available under Xcode4?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK universal app in Xcode uses two different xibs, so when "upgrading" to universal app - you actually have to write code to know which xibs to load as well as create separate xibs for iphone and ipad.

Comment: in Xcode 3 there was a possibility to selet an iPhone xib-file and create an iPad.xib - Version of that file. i think this feature was removed in Xcode4